# Customize Worklight Adapter URL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am building an iOS and Android Apps using Worklight Framework, the worklight server will be protected by IBM Security Access Manager (ISAM) SSO, and therefore the Apps can only be reaching the worklight server after passing the Security challenges. I've found some docs about this integration and it works as intended.

But the apps also offers some features that doesn't required login, in which the Security Manager shouldn't intercept the adapter request to worklight server. The only workaround that suggested by IBM is to create a URL mapping junction in ISAM that defines the URLs that can access by public, and those which shall not. for example **/worklight/public** and **/worklight/secured**

But the URL pattern for all worklight adapter are **/worklight/invoke?adapter=ADAPTER_NAME**, so do we have a way to create a customized URL for public and secured adapter, for example:

1. /worklight/public/invoke
2. /worklight/secued/invoke

EDIT 1: Worklight Version 6.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please mention the version of Worklight you are using.

One way to achieve this is to create and deploy the adapters in two different projects. That way the context root of both the adapters will be different. So, you'll have URLs such as 
`/Project1/invoke?...` and `Project2/invoke?...` which you can apply to your filters.

Comment: Do you have any example to invoke the adapter from "Project2" in case I deploy my Apps to "Project1"?

Comment: How do you want to invoke the adapter from Project2 ? From your question, I guess, you want to invoke an adapter in Project2 (and Project1) from a device. Also, please mention the version of Worklight you are using

Comment: Yes you are right, I will deploy my Apps under Project1, and how should the Apps to invoke adapter from both Project? *WL v6.0.

Comment: So will both adapters will be accessed by the SAME app ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I only have 1 Apps, you suggested me to deploy 2 project to separate the adapters.